# IPS solution for a medium sized web application

Tags: web-application, ids, azure

As part of application security compliance we are supposed to implement an IPS on our application. The application is basically an educational web portal where students can enrol for course assessment. The assessment will be done in the backend by professionals and the certificate is issued to the students. This involves payment also. The application is hosted in Kubernetes in AWS cloud.

We see that various levels of IPS are available in the market. Some includes threat intelligence models and SIEM modules. But for a small application like this, we don't think SIEM is not necessary. Also, taking into consideration that we are running short of budget, we would like to opt for a basic IPS that can effectively protect the web application.

I would like to invite suggestions. I am not looking for a specific tool recommendation, but rather a way of implementation.

Comment: This is a confusing question. You want an IPS on the *application* or the server? What do you want to *control* or mitigate or prevent? What's your desired outcome?

Comment: Implementing controls just to be compliant is not useful. What's the risk assessment?

Comment: Are you looking for a *web application firewall* (WAF)? There are good WAFs, but it may be painful to add all the exception required by your use case, so don't expect having an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: I would start with reading 2019 "Amazon EKS: User Guide" by Amazon Web Services - "Security in Amazon EKS" this book is available for free: http://a.co/3wCsB5L

Comment: @schroeder My aim is to protect the application from common injection attacks as well as network level attacks such as fragmentation attacks. We have cloudflare in place, but I don't think it can prevent network level attacks. Though, I am not sure implementing an IPS make any difference to the level of security that I am getting.